# What is $\bigwedge^{n-1} V$ and $V\otimes V$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space, say $\mathbb{R}^n$.What is $\wedge^{k} V$?

I just started reading about tensor product and wedge product yesterday, and I am using *Analysis on Manifold* by Munkres and his notations. Currently my understanding is that:

1. Given a $k$-tensor $f$ in $\mathcal{L}^k(V)$, and a $l$-tensor $g$ in $\mathcal{L}^l (V)$. We define the tensor product of $f$ and $g$ as a new $(l+m)$-tensor, such that $f\otimes g (v_1,\cdots,v_k,v_{k+1},\cdots,v_{k+l})=f(v_1,\cdots,v_k)g(v_{k+1},\cdots,v_{k+l})$
2. Similarly, if we only focus on alternating tensors, then we can define the wedge product between two alternating tensors. Let $f\in \mathcal{A}^k (V)$ and $g\in \mathcal{A}^k (V)$, then $f\wedge g$ will be in $\mathcal{A}^{k+l} (V)$ satisfying some properties, such as $f\wedge g = (-1)^{kl} g\wedge f$

But my book doesn't seem to cover wedge product of a vector space. So I read Wiki, and it defines $\bigwedge V$ in terms of tensor algebra of $V$, and found the following:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$. For any nonnegative integer k, we define the $k$-th tensor power of $V$ to be the tensor product of $V$ with itself k times:
>
> $T^{k}V=V^{\otimes k}=V\otimes V\otimes \cdots \otimes V$
>
> That is, $T^k V$ consists of all tensors on $V$ of order $k$.

Difference in notations confuse me, because how do you "tensor product" two vector space? I assume that $T^k (V) = \mathcal{L}^k (V)$? And if that's the case, I suppose that $\bigwedge^k V$ is just $\mathcal{A}^k(V)$? Namely the elemens in $\bigwedge^k V$ are just $k$-alternating tensors defined on $V$?

Comment: Did you look up the definition of tensor product of vector spaces?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, as I quoted.

Comment: No, you have quoted the tensor power. You are asking what the tensor product is.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I just read that and it's even more confusing. So when we say tensor product, it could mean tensor product of two vectors and tensor product of two multilinear functions, and they are different?

Comment: When we say tensor product of vector spaces, it means neither of those. It means the vector space we get as the tensor product (defined in any of the million different ways).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What does that mean? "the vector space we get as the tensor product"? Do you mean "the vector space we get as we tensor product everything in the vector space"? or "somehow we get a vector space, and this new vector space is a tensor product"? (whatever that means)

Comment: I mean the thing that is called the tensor product of those two vector spaces. This is a new vector space denoted $V\otimes W$ or $V\otimes_k W$ (where $V$ and $W$ are the two vector spaces we take the tensor product of and $k$ is the field we work over).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft OK. So the bottom line is, tensor product of two multilinear function, and tensor product of two vector spaces, are different things.